# How to adjust the frame space in a webapp?

Tags: html, web-applications, drag

I found this feature in an email webapp that lets a user drag a *frame splitter* to adjust the space each frame uses. 
What is it called and how to build that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard to program yourself with the help of a little jQuery, but there's a nice plugin for this also: [jQuery Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/)

Or this one: http://www.methvin.com/splitter/vsplitter.html

Or this one: http://jquery.jcubic.pl/splitter.php

enough samples available I would think...